# iOS encryption key derivation (from PIN code)

Tags: ios, encryption

iOS has recently requested me to confirm my PIN code which is used to encrypt my data.

If the PIN code is used to derivate the encryption key I find this weird since most PINs are a 4 or 6 digit number. Therefore that would make only 10^4 to 10^6 possible keys. I guess the PIN must be salted, yet if an attacker knows what is used to salt, it's still only 10^6 possibilities and therefore something very easy to bruteforce if a way is found to extract the encrypted data out of the device (or iCloud).

Can someone explain how Apple derivates the key from the PIN while still being at the top of encryption "Art"?

Thank you.

Comment: You only get 10 tries before it will lock you out. [30 if you also have a Mac] There's a decent article at https://marcan.st/2016/03/untangling-ios-pin-code-security/ even if it is a few years old - far too long to précis here.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Quite interesting since it provides an answer I'm going to put in the thread right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As provided by @Tetsujin the following link provides the answer: https://marcan.st/2016/03/untangling-ios-pin-code-security/

> are again encrypted using a key that is derived from the user’s PIN.
> This means that you need to know the PIN to access the data. **Deriving
> the key also requires a secret key available inside the iPhone’s CPU**.

Answer (score -1):

Even with the salt in the attackers' hands for example via reverse engineering, iOS has the [Security Lockout](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212951) feature which does not enable the user to try the PIN code more than a handful times.

If however the Security Lockout would be reverse engineered and disabled the encrypted data would be more easily bruteforced because like you said there would only be 10<sup>6</sup> amount of possible keys.